# Java - Server and Client not interacting (Socket)

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a small chat-program. The 2 classes, I have a problem with are the classes containing the clientside and the serverside of a socket. I want them to interact, sending a string from the server to the client, but the string isn't received apparently. I also don't get an error. Can someone explain, **why** this happens or **how to fix** it?

Codesnippet from the client:

```
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("WAITING");
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

Codesnippet from the server:

```
// Method of the code throws Exception
System.out.println("Waiting for someone to connect.");
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
System.out.println("Someone connected.");
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
while(true) {
    System.out.println("WRITING");
    pw.write("hi");
}
```

The output is currently:

server:

```
WRITING
WRITING
WRITING
WRITING
WRITING
...
```

client:

```
WAITING //only once
```

Comment: Post the whole code of the client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client expects a complete line:

```
br.readLine()
```

and blocks until the line is complete.

But the server only sends "hi" repeatedly, without ever sending any EOL character:

```
pw.write("hi");
```

So the line never ends, and the client keeps blocking.

Use `pw.println("hi");`

Answer (score 1):

The server buffer is not getting flushed. If you change `pw.write(...)` to `pw.println(...)` it should fix the issue - `println(...)` auto-flushes the buffer